# I need help, translating C code into Mips, anything is appreciated

Tags: c, mips

I'm currently in a class where we have to translate C into Mips, however, I am struggling with this assignment. Can anybody help me understand Mips better in order to know how to do this?

main questions: what is the difference between saving a register and loading it on the stack?
how do you create a function that takes in input arguments?
How do you make functions recursive?

Thank you!

C Code:

```
int f(int n, int m) {  
    if (n ≤ 0)  
        return m;  
    else  
        return f(n-1, n+m);
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/
Choose mips compiler.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to actually understand how to do this myself

Comment: Using a C compiler and studying its asm output is a completely valid way of getting hints on how to code in assembler.  The problem right now is your question is asking very very fundamental questions such that people are apt to just point you at a basic tutorial page.  At least with godbolt, you can play with it a bit and see how it outputs.  This should answer  your stack vs register and call questions.  Do you know C well enough to know what that code is doing?  And if so, why do you have an illegal operator in your if statement?

Comment: I do understand the C code, I just posted what was given to me by my professor

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output from GodBolt (with -O3 flags)

```
f:
    blez    $4,.L7
    move    $2,$5

.L3:
    addu    $2,$2,$4
    addiu   $4,$4,-1
    bne     $4,$0,.L3
    nop

.L7:
    j       $31
    nop
```

Of course if you turn this in as-is without understanding it, you are failing yourself and may very well get in trouble with your class.  Also notice that the compiler swapped your recursive function for an iterative one :)  Feel free to compile with different optimization levels to see just how messy the compiler can be.

Or... ask a TA, teacher, or fellow students of your class for help.

Comment: Id like to actually understand it myself, which is why I have those questions there, with a bit more explanation on those I think I might be able to figure this out